# Building Ionic Vue - vue loader not found in registry

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

I wanna build my Ionic Vue Project according to the Docs with Capacitor.

`ionic capacitor build android --prod`

Brings me the following error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@vue%2fvue-loader-v15 - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@vue/vue-loader-v15@15.9.8' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of '@vue/cli-service'
```

I already deleted the .lock file and reinstalled all packages but it still does not work. I meet all the system requirements according to the docs.

Here are my packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.5",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.2.5",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.2",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.1.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.5",
    "@ionic/vue": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^5.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^9.2.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.20",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-router": "4",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.2.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.15.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.15.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "cypress": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.6.0",
    "jest": "^27.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with
`ionic capacitor build android`

try to use

```
yarn add @capacitor/android
capacitor add andriod
ionic capacitor build android
```

my capacitor-cli version **3.3.4**